# How do I connect non-I2C devices to an I2C bus?

Tags: i2c, raspberry-pi, gpio, expander

I'm quite new to electronics and just trying to do my first Raspberry Pi based system: one diode, one pressure sensor and LCD 1602 with keypad shield (the one for an Arduino board). The way I'd like to connect all the devices is using I2C (the Raspberry Pi doesn't have much GPIO).

And here  comes the question: How can I possibly connect non-I2C devices to the I2C bus? I heard about different expanders, like the MCP23017, will that solve the problem?

Comment: Depends on what the non-I²C device requires. Can you get a bit more specific about the interface?

Comment: for instance mentioned above diode will be switched on and off. The LCD display with keypad shield is supposed to show some basic information about the system(like name of the user retrieved from the raspberry pi) and to send back some information(the signal to restart the system) if reset button on the shield is pressed. The pressure sensor is already designed as an I2C device.

Comment: If you meant the way, how devices supposed to be connected, then the LCD with keypad shield needs six analog ports to pull out the signal from the buttons and seven ports for digital signals. The diode needs only some kind of the control pin to be switched on and off.

Comment: @jippie could you, please, tell some possible solutions on the matter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible that the question represents a misunderstanding or miscommunication of the kind of connection desired: Not something to be connected to the I2C bus itself, but **to be controlled via some intermediary *I2C to GPIO* device**, which further is connected on the I2C bus.

The idea of non-I2C devices being connected to an I2C bus is meaningless. The I2C protocol has specific requirements, for the I2C master to address the slave device, and for communicating data in either direction.

The LCD mentioned in the question, for instance, works on a different set of communication protocols, using multiple GPIO pins, and (from the description) most likely does not recognize I2C. There are however I2C LCD modules available, which incorporate I2C slave functionality on board - either through an LCD controller or a dedicated microcontroller with I2C slave communication code. Instead of the basic LCD module mentioned, such an I2C display module would be required for use on an I2C bus.

I2C bus expanders cannot magically create I2C functionality on a connected device. What I2C bus expanders can do, however, is **provide additional GPIO pins**, which are then controlled by code from the Raspberry Pi or microcontroller through the expander, which itself responds to I2C commands.

Perhaps that is what is desired - in which case, sure, it will work but not as described: A GPIO-driven device such as the LCD module or an LED can be wired up to the expander's GPIO pins, and the expander is the device that is connected to the I2C bus.

Comment: Thank you! This answer is exactly what I expected to get here.